# Grails domains in plugins or on application?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-domain-class

Today i have a simple application with some domain class. Now i will create a plugin, but this plugin needs specifics domain classes.

The question is, i should create the domain classes on plugin or on application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create them as 'templates' and have them be created with the init script (like with spring security'). I hav done similar things and they work great. Take a look at how spring security does it to get a good idea.

Comment: Great @Orubel. it sounds like a good idea Have an example? Or documentation page?

Comment: Just download either the Grails Api Toolkit or Spring Security Core. Both use same methodology. Open up plugin and go to scripts/init to see how it's done and src/template to see the templates used.

Answer (score 0):

if plugin needs the domain classes, they must be defined either in the same plugin or in another plugin, which your plugin is using.

Comment: ok, but these domain classes in future will be shared with another plugin. i think it's  so confused

Comment: you should consider building a plugin hierarchy